# How do I store results of multiple case statement in different columns (that do not exist in the original table)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to query a table that has (user_id, segmentd_id, date) to create a new table like this:
[image]

so I was thinking about something like this but it doesn't work:

```
WITH Temp_seg as
SELECT
user_id, 
Segment1,
Segment2,
Segment3,
Segment4,
Segment5,
Segment6,
Segment7,
Segment8,
Segment9,
Segment10


(select 
user_id,
(case when segment_id in (1) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment1,
(case when segment_id in (2) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment2,
(case when segment_id in (3) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment3,
(case when segment_id in (4) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment4,
(case when segment_id in (5) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment5,
(case when segment_id in (6) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment6,
(case when segment_id in (7) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment7,
(case when segment_id in (8) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment8,
(case when segment_id in (9) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment9,
(case when segment_id in (10) then "Yes" else empty end) Segment10,

from Segments 
where date = last_7_days
and segment_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
group by user_id
```

Can someone help me out?
thanks

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  A clear explanation of the logic would also help.

Comment: I'm using postgresql, the logic is that in segment_id  there will be the values from 1 to 10, i need a new table keyed off the user id where for each user I mark yes on each columns where they belong to. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need:

```
select user_id
       , max(case when segmentd_id = 1 then 'Yes' end) Segment1
       , max(case when segmentd_id = 2 then 'Yes' end) Segment2
       , max(case when segmentd_id = 3 then 'Yes' end) Segment3
from segments
group by user_id
order by user_id
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eb636cab0a0a5fbac2e4f7db1863e24f)

If you will need to add the where caluse to filder the data for only last 7 days you can use this:

```
select user_id
       , max(case when segmentd_id = 1 then 'Yes' end) Segment1
       , max(case when segmentd_id = 2 then 'Yes' end) Segment2
       , max(case when segmentd_id = 3 then 'Yes' end) Segment3
from segments
where date_c >= CURRENT_DATE -7
group by user_id
order by user_id
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for!!